# What should be the number of hidden neurons?

Tags: neural-network

In a regression problem,to predict travel time based on some traffic data.I have

> 1500 data,input feature is 7 and output is single node,I want to use MLP(Multi layer perceptron),activation function = ReLU and backpropagation algo.

How many neurons should i choose for 1 hidden layer and also how many node i choose if i use 2 hidden layers? Any suggestion,please?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Comment: Very briefly, you haven't described your problem with nearly enough useful detail, and you've asked us to design a network for you.  Both of these are fatal to a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of hidden layers and dimensions generally must be determined empirically.

Here's some information to think about:

Many problems only require one hidden layer. Problems that are easy to break down into multiple steps (image processing for example) might benefit from more layers.

Adding more layers can allow the network to simply memorize training data (overfitting the function), so make sure you use separate testing data from your training set to test for this. The same issue arises with too many neurons in a layer.

Generally, choose a number of hidden neurons between the input size and the output size, then experiment from there.